# Divide list of tibbles by a list of tibbles in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Suppose I have a nested tibble in the following format:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
AccountNumber Tibble1          Tibble2         
         <int> <list>           <list>          
1             1 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2             2 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
3             3 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

This can be generated by the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble1 <- tibble(AccountNumber = 1:3, A_1 = 1, B_1 = 2, C_1 = 3) %>%
  group_by(AccountNumber) %>%
  nest(.key = "Tibble1")

tibble2 <- tibble(AccountNumber = 1:3, A_2 = 4, B_2 = 5, C_2 = 6) %>%
  group_by(AccountNumber) %>%
  nest(.key = "Tibble2")

tibble_joined <- left_join(tibble1, tibble2, by = "AccountNumber")
```

- **How would I create a third list of tibbles by dividing Tibble1 by Tibble 2?**

Essentially I would like the following format:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
AccountNumber Tibble1          Tibble2            Tibble3(Tibble2 / Tibble1)
         <int> <list>           <list>            <list>
1             1 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2             2 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
3             3 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

...where Tibble3 is simply the ratio of Tibble 2 over Tibble 1 of:

- Every column for
- Every Account Number

My attempts so far have been:

```
tibble_joined %>%
  group_by(AccountNumber) %>%
  mutate(Tibble3 = tibble(tibble2 / tibble1))
```

and

```
tibble_joined %>%
  group_by(AccountNumber) %>%
  summarise(Tibble3 = tibble2 / tibble1)
```

which both give this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

I've tried to find elegant solutions to this problem, but I can't find anything.

=========================================================================

I'm fully aware that my problem can be solved by the following:

```
tibble_Main %>%
  group_by(AccountNumber) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(A_Ratio = A_2 / A_1,
         B_Ratio = B_2 / B_1,
         C_Ratio = C_2 / C_2)
```

...which generates the following:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
# Groups: AccountNumber [3]
  AccountNumber   A_1   B_1   C_1   A_2   B_2   C_2 A_Ratio B_Ratio C_Ratio
          <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1             1  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00    4.00    2.50    1.00
2             2  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00    4.00    2.50    1.00
3             3  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00    4.00    2.50    1.00
```

...but this seems cumbersome, and will get annoying with many columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` from `purrr` to divide one `tibble` over another

```
library(purrr)
res <- tibble_joined %>% 
          mutate(Tibble3 = map2(Tibble1, Tibble2,  ~ as_tibble( .y/.x) %>%
                             rename_all(funs(sub('_.*', "_ratio", .)))))
res
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#   AccountNumber Tibble1          Tibble2          Tibble3         
#          <int> <list>           <list>           <list>          
#1             1 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
#2             2 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
#3             3 <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]> <tibble [1 x 3]>

res$Tibble3
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  A_ratio B_ratio C_ratio
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    4.00    2.50    2.00

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  A_ratio B_ratio C_ratio
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    4.00    2.50    2.00

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  A_ratio B_ratio C_ratio
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    4.00    2.50    2.00
```

NOTE: `purrr` is part of the `tidyverse` packages

Comment: @akrum, map2 seems to get the structure, but Tibble3 is coming back as a list of tibbles where each tibble has <NULL>s. Do you know why that would be happening?

Comment: @clarjoe I did the tibble1/tibble2, you can do change it to .y/.x

Comment: @akrum Ya, I noticed that. Flexibility is good. Is there a way to control the Tibble3's column names?

Comment: @clarkjoe  Updated the post with `rename`